# PHP Dynamic Namespaces in MVC

Tags: php, namespaces, autoloader

I'm starting a new app and have finally decided to join the new age using Namespaces. I'm finding myself constantly writing code like this:

```
 $dynamicControllerName = "MyController";
 $controllerName = "System\\App\\Controllers\\" . $dynamicControllerName;
 $controller = new $controller;
```

Anytime I try to use the `use` keyword it doesn't seem work (or I don't understand it correctly):

```
 use System\App\Controllers as Controller
```

And then

```
 $dynamicControllerName = "MyController";
 $controllerName = "Controller\\" . $dynamicControllerName;
 $controller = new $controller;
```

That makes my autoloader think the path is my base path plus "/Controller/MyController" rather than the desired "/System/App/Controllers/MyController". I've tried varying combinations of *with* and *without* the prefix slashes.

A real world example of what I'm attempting looks like this (trying to get MyController):

```
 namespace System\App\Lib;

 use System\App\Controllers as Controller;

 class Router
 {
    public function dispatch(Request $request)
    {
        //...some dispatch code here

        // Instantiate Controller (THIS DOESNT WORK)
        $controllerName = "Controller\\" . $request->controller;
        $controller = new $controllerName($param1, $param2);

        //...some dispatch code here
    }
 }
```

I would think the above would request a class from my autoloader called **System\App\Controllers\MyController** and then I can flip the slashes and add a file extension and voila. Instead it comes through as **Controller\MyController** which doesn't exist. Is it because the **Router** class is in a different namespace? What am I missing?

TL;DR; In an MVC pattern, how can I dynamically instantiate a class instance without having to type the fully qualified namespace every time?

P.S. I'm using PHP 5.4.15

**EDIT**

Autoloading is setup with:

```
// Define AutoLoading
spl_autoload_register(array('System\App', 'autoload'));
```

The autoload function:

```
/**
* Autoloading via PSR-0 Namespacing
*/
protected static function autoload($className = false)
{
    var_dump($className);
    if($className)
    {
        $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
        $fileName  = '';
        $namespace = '';
        if ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, '\\')) {
            $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
            $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
            $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        }
        $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
        $fileName = App::$SYS_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
        include_once $fileName;
    }
}
```

When I do dumps of the `$className` I can see whether PHP is recognizing a namespace or not.

Comment: what mvc framework are you using?

Comment: A custom one I had built a few months back. I'm rewriting it to use namespaces.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but, are you use `require` or `require_once` directive also, right?

Comment: @DonCallisto I added my autoload function to the question. And yes, I'm attempting to include the file.

Comment: @tereško - now you're being ridiculous.  The question asker clearly mentions "The MVC Pattern".  This is a clear use of the MVC tag.